# ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error when using proxies

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

I am currently using seleniumwire and IPRoyal to access the page. My page works fine for cetain website but when accessing certain webpage, I am getting the error below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.50)
```

The code I used is very simple

```
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc

def main():

    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    seleniumwire_options = {
        'proxy': {
            'http': 'http://username:password@geo.iproyal.com:12321',
            'https': 'https://username:password@geo.iproyal.com:12321',
        }
    }


    driver = uc.Chrome(
        options=chrome_options,
        seleniumwire_options=seleniumwire_options,
    )
    driver.get("https://driverpracticaltest.dvsa.gov.uk")

    time.sleep(10000)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is there any way to avoid this issues whilst using undetected_chromedriver ( I don't want to use "raw" selenium)